# Get a sub 3d-array given a list of indices using itemgetter

Tags: arrays, python-2.7, numpy, operators

l have a 3D array called **my_data** of shape **(96, 18, 3)**. I would like to get only some values given the index of axis=1. axis=1 is of length 18

To do so, l tried the following:

```
from operator import itemgetter
index_1= [3,4,6,7,9,10,12,13]
getter=itemgetter(3,4,6,7,9,10,12,13)
getter(my_data)
```

However it applies getter on the first axis that reduces 96 to 8 . What l want is to apply getter on the second axis so that to get **my_data** of shape **(96, 8, 3)**.

I tried also :

```
my_data[:,getter,:]
```

I get the following error :
*** IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices

Comment: `itemgetter` is a list convenience operator; we don't normally try to use on numpy arrays.  That it works on first dimension means it just treats the array as a list of arrays.  `numpy` lets you index with a list directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you not use `itemgetter` and simply provide your list as an indexer:

```
index_1= [3,4,6,7,9,10,12,13]
my_data[:,index_1,:]
```

On a dataset such as yours:

```
>>> my_data.shape
(96, 18, 3)

>>> my_data[:,index_1,:].shape
(96, 8, 3)
```

**Minimal example:**

Take the 2nd and 4th element of dimension `1` of a `(5,5,3)` array:

```
>>> my_data = np.random.random((5,5,3))
>>> my_data
array([[[ 0.48913302,  0.65967146,  0.16984338],
        [ 0.65309136,  0.61112866,  0.48317725],
        [ 0.75979879,  0.1788647 ,  0.84855963],
        [ 0.95604821,  0.91686885,  0.04629087],
        [ 0.32021119,  0.17582171,  0.44410709]],

       [[ 0.40507398,  0.33866034,  0.57994344],
        [ 0.35664701,  0.82952864,  0.48164719],
        [ 0.53201074,  0.74598244,  0.025587  ],
        [ 0.29090129,  0.85763979,  0.12372515],
        [ 0.66274253,  0.45789019,  0.5960151 ]],

       [[ 0.98733701,  0.21920232,  0.25870197],
        [ 0.83877241,  0.74712859,  0.12972104],
        [ 0.99349399,  0.58134955,  0.90017913],
        [ 0.21030304,  0.68324321,  0.36743921],
        [ 0.26277439,  0.30750822,  0.10385251]],

       [[ 0.73189247,  0.49511839,  0.04785461],
        [ 0.62492651,  0.92238879,  0.04875051],
        [ 0.6779602 ,  0.7643024 ,  0.17460262],
        [ 0.57072683,  0.87087793,  0.5888601 ],
        [ 0.37419042,  0.39583678,  0.30297916]],

       [[ 0.51922434,  0.21364451,  0.32678503],
        [ 0.66437971,  0.6550304 ,  0.61334286],
        [ 0.16475464,  0.84246673,  0.32644154],
        [ 0.56004586,  0.02378533,  0.61112593],
        [ 0.59555996,  0.88077068,  0.44648423]]])

>>> index_1 = [1,3]

>>> my_data[:, index_1, :]
array([[[ 0.65309136,  0.61112866,  0.48317725],
        [ 0.95604821,  0.91686885,  0.04629087]],

       [[ 0.35664701,  0.82952864,  0.48164719],
        [ 0.29090129,  0.85763979,  0.12372515]],

       [[ 0.83877241,  0.74712859,  0.12972104],
        [ 0.21030304,  0.68324321,  0.36743921]],

       [[ 0.62492651,  0.92238879,  0.04875051],
        [ 0.57072683,  0.87087793,  0.5888601 ]],

       [[ 0.66437971,  0.6550304 ,  0.61334286],
        [ 0.56004586,  0.02378533,  0.61112593]]])
```